# selenium не подгружается указанный профиль браузера

Tags: selenium

Всем привет.
Хочу что бы selenium подгрузил профиль моего основного браузера, но selenium при запуске его не подгружает.

Путь к профилю беру от сюда:
[image: путь к профилю который хочу подгрузить]

Вот так функция вызывающая selenium код:

```
def get_html_Chrome_categories(link):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default")
    dir_chromedriver = (os.path.abspath(os.curdir) + '\chromedriver.exe').replace("\\", "\\\\").strip() # путь к chromedriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=dir_chromedriver)
    driver.get(link)
    html = driver.page_source
    return html
```

При запуске функции подгружает такое вот окно:

[image: запуск selenium]

**Вопрос**: в чем ошибка ? как мне подгрузить свой личный профиль гугл хрома ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно лучше поздно, чем никогда.
Ваш код нужно исправить.

Вместо:

```
  options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default")
```

Вот это:

```
  options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
  options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
```